# How to open multiple concatenated hyperlinks at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I used the Concatenate function to join links like this:

```
Column 1: http://twitter.com/
Column 2: username
Column 3: http://twitter.com/username
```

I actually wrote the function like this:

```
=hyperlink(CONCATENATE(cell1,cell2))
```

And now it shows all the cells as links.
Next, I wen to Visual Basic and added the following module (which lets me open multiple links at once):

```
Sub Hyperlink_Follow()
For Each c In Selection
On Error Resume Next
c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Next
End Sub
```

Next, I selected the links and run the macros, but nothing happened.

If you follow the steps above and run links like:

```
http://google.com
http://twitter.com
http://reddit.com
```

It works fine. The problem is with the concatenated links.

Any idea why? Workarounds around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it fails because hyperlinks created with the `HYPERLINKS` Excel function aren't included in the `HYPERLINKS` VBA collection for the cell. Try using `Debug.Print c.Hyperlinks(1).Address` and note that it doesn't print the URLs for the cells creating a hyperlink formulaically. This is further backed up by trying to edit the hyperlink in Excel. Right-clicking on a cell with the `HYPERLINK` function only gives you the "Remove Hyperlink" option and clicking it does nothing. A regular hyperlink lets you Edit, Open, or Remove it.

Here is a workaround that first tries to pull the `HYPERLINK(1).ADDRESS` value and, if that fails, pulls the cells text value instead. Note that this won't work if you use the `friendly_name` parameter in your `HYPERLINK` formula as that will be read as the cell value instead.

```
Sub Hyperlink_Follow()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim url As String
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        url = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        url = c.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        If url = "" Then url = c.Value
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink url
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that I also added a 3 second pause between each URL because I found that opening too many at once tends to just overwrite the last window created instead of making a new one. That might just be because I'm at work on IE. You can test that and remove it if it isn't needed.

Comment: I can't find any reference on *why* this is, but I verified that hyperlinks created by formula using `=hyperlink` are not included in hyperlinks collection. e.g. `For Each Hyperlink In Worksheets(1).Hyperlinks MsgBox (Hyperlink.Address)Next`